# How to connect separate physical devices to same virtual network in VMWARE

Tags: network, vmware, virtual

I am trying to create a vitual active directory network at home. I am trying to do this in VMWare.

I have 2 actual physical computers. Here is the plan:

**1st Physical Machine: Using vmware create the following:**

```
- Windows server 2016 (Domain Controller/DHCP server)
- Win Server 2012 (mail server)
- Centos 7 (web server)
- win 10 (host)
- Win 7 (host)
```

**2nd Physical Machine: Using VMware create the following:**

```
- Win 10 (host) x2
- Win 7 (host) x2
- Win XP (host)
```

All of the virtual machines on the 1st physical device will be in a self contained virtual network. However, I want to connect virtual devices on the 2nd physical device to the same virtual network on the 1st physical device

How do I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations are off-topic. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

On the vHosts' vSwitches, you use *port groups* to connect VMs to a common network. These port groups can be associated with VLAN IDs for a physical network which you need to use to connect both vSwitches.

Use the same VLAN ID on both hosts. On the physical switch, add the VLAN as tagged to the host ports and you're set. (Of course, the vSwitch needs to have a physical NIC connected to the physical switch. The physical NIC can be shared with other port groups/VLANs in the same vSwitch.)

If you want to be able to vMotion the VMs you need to name the port groups in the exact same way.